# How to call the controller when changing tab in tabbarcontroller? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a search tab in the tab bar controller and a songs controller. I would like to jump to search tab when user click into one of the button in the songs controller and start searching. I am using this code to change tab

```
 self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

this above code works but i would like to call the search function in the search tab when changing tabs.

Comment: You need to implement the UITabBarControllerDelegate to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be **notified** implementing the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol in your ViewControllers

You need add this line in your viewDidLoad for your viewControllers

```
self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
```

and implementing this method of `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol

```
public func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
```

You will be notified when a new viewController is selected in your `tabBarController`

Comment: if i directly call this  self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 , it does not call the delegate function. i don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling your search function in viewWillAppear of your search view controller?

viewWillAppear will be invoked everytime you enter the viewcontroller in the tab bar.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp I wanted post it as a comment, but I couldn't find an option for that in the app

Comment: Unfortunately SO is quite limited, you should gain a little bit of standing before being able to post comments. It is not much, so keep trying to answer questions avoiding comments. I know it is hard, but it is so just in the beginning.